# Automatically start a project on netbeans startup

Tags: windows, netbeans

**Any possibilities?**

I'm using windows 10.

I want to start a netbeans project on netbeans startup in Windows.

Help me to find a solution if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a few years since I used NetBeans, and my memory wants to tell me that it always reopened the previous project on startup – apparently not (did you search preferences, to see if there is an option?).

You don’t say if you want to always launch the previous project, or a particular project, which might not have been the last opened project.

Since you are a programmer, the easiest way to automate ***any*** Windows program is to write a few lines of [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) script.

For instance[this page](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/notepad/notepad.htm) shows how to automate the opening of Notepad, automatically type some text and then close Notepad:

```
Run("notepad.exe")
WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
Send("This is some text.")
WinClose("Untitled - Notepad")
WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Save")
;WinWaitActive("Notepad", "Do you want to save") ; When running under Windows XP
Send("!n")
```

Trivial, huh?  I am sure that you can quickly convert that so open NetBeans and send Alt+F …. Whatever, maybe R for recent projects, then 1 … maybe just Open project and code to control the file selection dialog?

AutoIt is a fantastic and free tool for automatizing Windows tasks. It replaces a human in that it can both send mouse/key events, and also verify what appears on the screen.

Its simple scripting language includes variables, loops, branching, procedures, etc and is simple to learn, but powerful enough for complex applications. It hasn’t let me down  yet, in almost 20 years of use.